# Remove image from post_content on save_post

Tags: functions, content, save-post

I'm trying to setup a function in functions.php that removes an image from the post_content on save. Everything works up until the time I'm trying to save the content, the page just hangs and I get a '500 Internal Server' error.

```
function remove_post_image( $post_ID ){

  // get the post
  $the_post = get_post($post_ID);

  // get the content of the post
  $post_content = $the_post->post_content;

  // replace any images
  $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $post_content);

  // save the post
  $my_post = array();
  $my_post['ID'] = $post_ID;
  $my_post['post_content'] = $content;

  // Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );   

  return $post_ID;
}
add_action('save_post', 'remove_post_image');
```

I fear I'm missing something very basic. Can anyone spot something I'm doing wrong?

---

*edit*

Already I see how silly this was setup. I'm having success with the following, but still would like to know if this is the best way? I'm using content_save_pre action...

```
function remove_post_image( $content ){

  // replace any images
  $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);

  return $content;
}
add_action('content_save_pre', 'remove_post_image');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content_save_pre` would be a much better hook for stripping the images, and as for setting post thumbnail as post Meta you can use `save_post` since the first hook gets fired before post Id is set and you need that for `update_post_meta`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function calls `wp_update_post()`, which calls `wp_insert_post()` which runs `save_post` action, which fires guess what? Your function.

It would be better to use something like `wp_insert_post_data` which is meant to filter data, rather than `save_post` action that is meant to merely indicate that data was already processed.

Comment: Haha, ok so the internal server error was from the endless functions calling eachother. Going to look at `wp_insert_post_data` -- thanks!

Comment: Found a good solution using content_save_pre... But will I run into the same issue if I want to use `update_post_meta` inside that function? My end goal is I want to remove the image from the content and then use `update_post_meta` to set a featured image.