# Not work function add width and height at save post

Tags: php

```
add_action( 'content_save_pre', 'add_image_dimensions' );

function add_image_dimensions( $content ) {

    preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images);

    if (count($images) < 1)
        return $content;

foreach ($images[0] as $image) {
    preg_match_all( '/(alt|title|src|width|class|id|height)=("[^"]*")/i', $image, $img );

    if ( !in_array( 'src', $img[1] ) )
        continue;

    if ( !in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || !in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ) {
        $src = $img[2][ array_search('src', $img[1]) ];
        $alt = in_array( 'alt', $img[1] ) ? ' alt=' . $img[2][ array_search('alt', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $title = in_array( 'title', $img[1] ) ? ' title=' . $img[2][ array_search('title', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $class = in_array( 'class', $img[1] ) ? ' class=' . $img[2][ array_search('class', $img[1]) ] : '';
        $id = in_array( 'id', $img[1] ) ? ' id=' . $img[2][ array_search('id', $img[1]) ] : '';

        list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( str_replace( "\"", "" , $src ) );
        $html = '';

        if (($width != 0) || ($height != 0)) {
            $html = ' width="%d" height="%d" ';
        }

        $image_tag = sprintf( '<img loading="lazy" src=%s%s%s%s%s' . $html . '/>', $src, $alt, $title, $class, $id, $width, $height );
        $content = str_replace($image, $image_tag, $content);
    }
}

return $content;
}
```

This code should add width and height to pictures when saving post, but it doesn't. Why?

Help me please.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: notice that you modify `$content` but then you don't return it, filters _always_ return something. If you don't return something, then it's the same as `return '';`

Comment: How will it be correct?

Comment: hmm you do return the content, I didn't notice because of the incorrect indentation, so that's not the cause, please ignore my first comment

Comment: Can I ask why you used `content_save_pre`? I checked the official WP docs and could not find that filter, and Adam Browns hooks database suggests it's not used in post saving. WP image blocks should also be adding widths and heights as well as `srcset` attributes by default

Comment: I saw this hook here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21805/remove-image-from-post-content-on-save-post

And I insert pictures directly into the article

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/field_no_prefix_save_pre/

Comment: and you are absolutely sure that your filter does not run? Or maybe it does run but does not find any images? Keep in mind that regular expressions can't parse HTML unless it's extremely simple, to parse and modify HTML you need to use an XML Parser. This filter also won't run on images inserted from shortcodes or from blocks rendered on the frontend/on demand. The answer you linked to is also 10 years old

Comment: `add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_image_dimensions' ); `- WORK

`add_action( 'content_save_pre', 'add_image_dimensions' );`
OR
`add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'add_image_dimensions' );` - NOT work :-(

Comment: Example of an inserted picture `<a href="https://....png" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="..."><img class="..." alt="..." src="https://....png"></a>`